# leer info publica de smart card eDNI (uruguay)

Tags: c#, smartcard

Quiero leer la informacion publica de un DNI electronico, Documento Nacional de Identificacion con chip electronico, una smart card iso 7816.

de Uruguay

estas son las especificaciones de AGESIC : https://centroderecursos.agesic.gub.uy/web/seguridad/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Gu%C3%ADa+de+uso+de+CI+electr%C3%B3nica+a+trav%C3%A9s+de+APDU

Aqui explica todo el tema de los comandos APDU

Este es un ejemplo en lenguaje C

https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-c.html

Este es un ejemplo en lenguaje Python

https://medium.com/overactive/firma-digital-uruguay-c74ab12e586

Este es un github en java, yo opino que no funciona, pero no lo ejecute

https://github.com/agesic-eid/Interfaz-datosci-apdu

este es otro ejemplo de github en java

https://github.com/eIDuy/apdu-services

este es otro codigo en python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#############################################################################################
#   Algunos de los metodos del codigo publicado por Gustavo Azambuja en :                   # 
#   https://gist.github.com/gazambuja/a55b75422a5a18c50e6d1ba7f5f44eea                      #
#   fueron refactorizados y comentados para su uso en el proyecto de seguridad de la        #
#   Universidad Catolica del Uruguay en el primer semestre de 2018 por el grupo 9 :         #
#   Facundo Hernandez, Francisco Perdomo, Ricardo Umpierrez                                 #
#############################################################################################

import hashlib, sys, time
from smartcard.CardType import ATRCardType, AnyCardType
from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest
from smartcard.CardConnection import CardConnection
from smartcard.util import toHexString, toBytes

action = userpin = stringhash = False

########### COMANDOS PRECARGADOS ####################
#               | CLA | INS | P1 | P2  |  LC |      DATA  ...                                  
selectIAS =     [0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0C, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x63, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00]
verifyPIN =     [0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x11, 0x0C]

MSE_SET_DST =   [0x00, 0x22, 0x41, 0xB6, 0x06]
PSO_HASH =      [0x00, 0x2A, 0x90, 0xA0, 0x20]
PSO_CDS =       [0x00, 0x2A, 0x9E, 0x9A, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00]
####################################################

if( len(sys.argv) == 1 ):
    print "Faltan argumentos"
else:
    action = sys.argv[1]
    userpin = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 3 else False
    stringhash = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv) > 3 else False

cardtype = ATRCardType( toBytes( "3B 7F 94 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 03 00 EF 12 0F FF 82 90 00" ) ) # Solo eCI de UY
cardrequest = CardRequest( timeout=20, cardType=cardtype )

if (len(cardrequest.getReaders()) == 0 ):
    print "Lector no conectado"

def encrypt_string(hash_string):
    sha_signature = hashlib.sha256(hash_string.encode()).hexdigest()
    return sha_signature

def enviarAPDU(cmd):
    data, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit(cmd)
    return [data, sw1, sw2];

def toHex(str):
    m = len(str)
    lst = []
    for i in xrange(0, m, 2):
        lst.append( int('0x' + str[i] + str[i + 1], 16) )
    return lst

def toPinHex(pin):
    m = len(pin)
    lst = []
    for i in xrange(0, 12, 1):
        if(i >= m):
            lst.append( int('0x00', 16))
        else:
            lst.append( int('0x3' + pin[i], 16))
    return lst

def init():

    global cardservice
    cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()
    cardservice.connection.connect( CardConnection.T0_protocol )

    ########### COMANDO selectIAS ################
    data, sw1, sw2 = enviarAPDU( selectIAS )          
    if ( sw1 != 0x90 and sw2 != 0x0 ) :
        print "ERROR AL LEER DOCUMENTO"
    else:
        time.sleep(1)

    ########### COMANDO verifyPIN ################
    data, sw1, sw2 = enviarAPDU( verifyPIN + toPinHex(userpin) )
    if ( sw1 == 0x90 and sw2 == 0x0 ) :

        ########### COMANDO MSE_SET_DST ################
        data, sw1, sw2 = enviarAPDU( MSE_SET_DST + [0x84, 0x01, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x02] )

        ########### COMANDO PSO_HASH ################
        data, sw1, sw2 = enviarAPDU( PSO_HASH + [0x90, 0x19] + MIHASH )

        ########### COMANDO PSO_Compute Digital Signature: ################
        data, sw1, sw2 = enviarAPDU( PSO_CDS )

        print encrypt_string(toHexString(data).replace(" ", ""))

    else :
        print "PIN INVALIDO"

###########################################################################
### Hay dos acciones definidas:                                         ###
###     - readerData ( void ) : imprime la marca y modelo del Lector    ###
###     - firmar (pin, string): hace un hash y encripta con la clave    ###
###                             privada un string pasado por parametro  ###
###########################################################################

if ( action == 'readerData' ):
    print "reader" + str(cardrequest.getReaders()[0])

elif ( action == 'firmar' ):
    MIHASH = toHex(encrypt_string(stringhash))
    init()
else:
    print "ACCION NO DEFINIDA"
```

mi desconocimiento de python y mi escaso conocimiento de java me impiden encontrar equivalentes en C#, pese a ello e escrito el siguiente codigo que funciona, pero no me brinda todos los datos publicos de la smart card

```
con la dll System.Security

con este using:
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            string certSubject;
            string certGetName;
            string certFriendlyName;
            string certGetEffectiveDateString;
            string certGetExpirationDateString;
            string certGetIssuerName;
            string certGetKeyAlgorithm;
            string certGetKeyAlgorithmParametersString;
            string certGetPublicKeyString;
            string certGetRawCertDataString;
            string certGetSerialNumberString;
            string certIssuer;
            string certSerialNumber;
            string certThumbprint;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (store.Certificates.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
                {
                    if (cert.Issuer.Contains("Ministerio del Interior"))
                    {
                        certFriendlyName = cert.FriendlyName;
                        certGetEffectiveDateString = cert.GetEffectiveDateString();
                        certGetExpirationDateString = cert.GetExpirationDateString();
                        certGetIssuerName = cert.GetIssuerName();
                        certGetKeyAlgorithm = cert.GetKeyAlgorithm();
                        certGetKeyAlgorithmParametersString = cert.GetKeyAlgorithmParametersString();
                        certGetName = cert.GetName();
                        certGetPublicKeyString = cert.GetPublicKeyString();
                        certGetRawCertDataString = cert.GetRawCertDataString();
                        certGetSerialNumberString = cert.GetSerialNumberString();
                        certIssuer = cert.Issuer;
                        certSerialNumber = cert.SerialNumber;
                        certSubject = cert.Subject;
                        certThumbprint = cert.Thumbprint;
                        sb.Append("certFriendlyName : " + certFriendlyName + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetEffectiveDateString : " + certGetEffectiveDateString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetExpirationDateString : " + certGetExpirationDateString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetIssuerName : " + certGetIssuerName + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetKeyAlgorithm : " + certGetKeyAlgorithm + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetKeyAlgorithmParametersString : " + certGetKeyAlgorithmParametersString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetName : " + certGetName + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetPublicKeyString : " + certGetPublicKeyString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetRawCertDataString : " + certGetRawCertDataString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certGetSerialNumberString : " + certGetSerialNumberString + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certIssuer : " + certIssuer + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certSerialNumber : " + certSerialNumber + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certSubject : " + certSubject + Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append("certThumbprint : " + certThumbprint + Environment.NewLine);

                    }
                }
            }
```

por otro lado he escrito este otro codigo, pero no consigo encontrar los comandos APDU correctos para obtener los datos

```
using PCSC;

 private void bLeoCIe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SCardContext hContext = new SCardContext();
            hContext.Establish(SCardScope.System);
            string[] szReaders = hContext.GetReaders();
            if (szReaders.Length <= 0)
            {
                // no hay smartcard
            }
            else
            {                
                SCardReader reader = new SCardReader(hContext);
                SCardError err = reader.Connect(szReaders[0], SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.T0 | SCardProtocol.T1);

                CheckErr(err);
                IntPtr pioSendPci = SCardPCI.T0;
                switch (reader.ActiveProtocol)
                {
                    case SCardProtocol.T0:
                        pioSendPci = SCardPCI.T0;
                        break;
                    case SCardProtocol.T1:
                        pioSendPci = SCardPCI.T1;
                        break;                    
                }
                byte[] pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0A, 0xA0,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd1, ref pbRecvBuffer);

                CheckErr(err);
                StringBuilder sr = new StringBuilder();
                sr.Append("response : ");
                for (int i = 0; i < pbRecvBuffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    sr.Append(pbRecvBuffer[i]); //0:x2
                }


                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd2 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd2, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                sr = new StringBuilder();
                sr.Append("response : ");
                for (int i = 0; i < pbRecvBuffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    sr.Append(pbRecvBuffer[i]); //0:x2
                }



                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd3 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x70, 0x00 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd3, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd4 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x70, 0x01 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd4, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd5 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x70, 0x02 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd5, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd6 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0C, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x63, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd6, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd7 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x70, 0x04 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd7, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd8 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0A, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd8, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);

                pbRecvBuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] cmd9 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
                err = reader.Transmit(pioSendPci, cmd9, ref pbRecvBuffer);
                CheckErr(err);


                hContext.Release();
            }
}

 static void CheckErr(SCardError err)
        {
            if (err != SCardError.Success)
            {
                // error
            }
        }
```

la libreria que utilice es: PCSC y PCSC.iso7816

el cmd2 me manda un array de 256 caracteres todos en 0 y todos los otros cmd1 ... cmd9 solo un array de  2 caracteres

si alguien tiene codigo que funcione con otros dni, me interesaria pues estoy preparando software para zona turistica de Uruguay y eso facilitaria la operativa, ademas no tengo dni para experimentar.

pregunta:
    a) que libreria debo usar para leer los datos de la smart card ?
    b) como consulto con comandos APDU el ATRCardType ?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo de la documentación que indicas, el primer comando que te recomienda ejecutar es:

CLA: 00 INS: A4 P1:04 P2:00 LC:0C DATA: A0 00 00 00 18 40 00 00 01 63 42 00 00

Con eso seleccionaras el applet correcto y podrás continuar enviando comandos, el que tu colocas como cmd1 no lo veo igual al de la documentación.

Para el resto de comandos, hay que seguir la documentación, indica lo que debes enviar y lo que deberías esperar como respuesta.

La libreria que yo he utilizado para trabajar con tarjetas mifare y lectores PCSC es la winscard.dll de windows. Por tu código creo que ya la estas utilizando.